# How do you ensure that your Google Cloud Run app is protected from being overloaded with requests?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-billing

I have created a simple Google Cloud Run helper program (does not handle any personal data nor does it make use of any storage facilities) and have implemented a public interface for it within a website (using HTML requests).  I do not plan to add any user authentication, and I have also open-sourced the code within the Cloud Run container.

Should there be any further steps I should take to protect the container from malicious users?  Could someone just overload the app with requests, exceeding the free invocation limit for the container (resulting in myself being billed)?  I mainly just want to ensure that I am never billed for the Cloud Run app, given that it is simply meant to act as a small helper tool for a limited number of users.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a broad, open-ended question that will probably be closed for "lack of focus," see [ask].  Search on "denial of service attack" for sites with introductions to the problem and some of the solutions.  You might also search on google cloud to see if there are tools / settings / policies to shut down access when some billing threshold is crossed.  If you narrow the question to "how to I shut off access after $x in requests" or similar that *might* be narrow enough to be OK, but that still might belong at ServerFault.com instead of here.

Comment: If you have enabled `allow-unauthenticated` then anyone can access your Cloud Run service. You have no protection. Implement authorization and only allow authorized users to access your endpoint.

Comment: Maybe consider Cloud Endpoints and quotas ... to limit the number of calls per minute ... https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/quotas-overview

Comment: Thanks all for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should there be any further steps I should take to protect the container from malicious users?

**Always**, protecting your apps and services from malicious users is always a must. As  **John Hanley** very well point out, if you are not using any type of authentication, you are therefore leaving one door open to more malicious attacks/users than if you implement some kind of authentication.

As he mentioned, if you have enabled `allow-unauthenticated` you are basically open your Cloud Run services to the public. This is not entirely bad, but it is another way to malicious users to attack your services.

You will find more information about unauthenticated access [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/public).

I highly recommend you to authenticate your Cloud Run services always if you can. As stated in the [authentication overview for Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/overview):

> All Cloud Run services **are deployed privately by default**, which means that they can't be accessed without providing authentication credentials in the request.

Furthermore, **by default**, services are only callable by **project owners**, **editors**, and **Cloud Run admins and developers**.

To authenticate end-users in your Cloud Run's services you can refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users) provided, but in summary:

> Most applications handle requests from end users, and it's a best practice to restrict access to only the allowed end users. In order to accomplish this, **you can integrate Google Sign-In and grant users the roles/run.invoker IAM role**, or **implement Firebase Authentication** and manually validate their credentials.

Note that Cloud Run does not assist in the sharing of sessions between container instances, thus not guarantying session affinity to a specific container instance.

Furthermore, [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips#container-security) you will find further information regarding security tips in Cloud Run that can help you improve your Cloud Run service's security.

Finally, as **Kolban** said, you could also use **Cloud Endpoints** in order to limit the quantity and number of request per minute, as seen [here.](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/quotas-overview#limit_the_number_of_requests_per_minute) This will ensure that you will not be billed further that what you would like to.

You will find a [complete list of other services](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/using-gcp-services#recommended-services) that you can use with Cloud Run in order to improve not only the end-user experience but also your security.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply!  Unfortunately, I think that if I add some form of user authentication, this will make the app somewhat more cumbersome to use and detract from its value.  I'll try adding Cloud Endpoints in order to limit the number of requests, and monitor billing to prevent any unwanted issues from occurring.

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 solutions

- The built in solution is to set a [maxInstance param](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/max-instances) to limit the number of spawn instance and reduce the cost. However, the malicious attacker can deny your service with sustainable traffic (not enough instance to serve all the request, good and bad!)
- Add an API management layer, like Cloud Endpoint or Apigee. But it's an additional layer to implement and to pay. [Cloud Endpoint is free but implies to have an API key for performing the quotas limitation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/quotas-overview). I don't know enough Apigee, but it's an entreprise grade (and pricing) solution, and I'm sure it implements rate limit on IP.

Comment: Thanks for your input @guillaume! I think I will try lower the maxInstance param substantially, as well as try add in Cloud Endpoint limiting.

Comment: In this case, set an alert on the http 429 error code. This code is returned in case of too many requests according with the available/possibles instances that you have on Cloud Run.